# Scala extend Java class with varargs constructor

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, constructor, variadic-functions

I have a java class with a varargs constructor:

```
class Foo {
   this(Bar... bars) { 
      ...
   }
```

How would I extend this class in Scala?

```
//doesnt compile
class NooFoo(bars: Bar*) extends Foo(bars)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

`class NooFoo(bars: Bar*) extends Foo(bars:_*)`

Since bars is a Seq[Bar],and Foo(bars:Seq[Bar]) is not a constructor of java class Foo,so it doesn't compile.